# Why is this `set` accessor not working?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have the following property in my model:

```
//PRODUCTS
private ICollection<int> _productIds;

[NotMapped]
public ICollection<int> ProductIds
{
    get { return Products.Select(s => s.Id).ToList(); }
    set { _productIds = value; }
}
```

When my code returns a new instance of this model, the `set` accessor doesn't seem to take.  In other words, I can see that the `get` accessor is appropriately returning a collection of product ids, but when I attempt to assign using the `set`, the value is an empty `List<int>`.  For example:

```
var result = new Application
{
    Id = application.Id,
    . . .
    ProductIds = application.ProductIds //<--this is a list of integers, 
                        // but the new "result" object shows an empty list.
};
```

Comment: What is `Products` and how do you expect setting the `productIds` field to change the value of `Products`?

Comment: Why aren't you returning the _productIds in the get accessor? That way you'll be always getting and setting the private property _productIds. May be the Products list you're returning is empty. Did you check that?

Comment: Thank you.  `Products` represents products related to my `Application` entity.  `ProductIds` just needs to be a list of related product ids.   I am new to customizing the `get; set;` accessors.  I must be missing something obvious as @wilsotobianco points out.  Will check . . .

Comment: Thanks to you both, it is sorted now per the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unusual to have `get` and `set` for one property to work of different sources. You may want to remove set altogether if you always read the value from somewhere else.

Maybe you are looking to override value of the property (i.e. for unit testing) like this:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public ICollection<int> ProductIds
    {
        get { return _productIds != null ?
             _productIds // return one that was "set"
             : Products.Select(s => s.Id).ToList(); // read from DB
        } 
        set { _productIds = value; }
    }
```

Comment: That was the ticket, thanks!  Can accept in one minute.

Comment: @MatthewPatrickCashatt depending on what you are doing you may want to check `Lazy<T>` - which would be better if you need to cache result rather than overwrite it.